# How can I train Neural network where same features have different labels?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, classification

I am new to the machine learning. I did some simple models for regression and classification problems, but have trouble to train this NN on these data as follows... What am I doing wrong?
Data:

```
train_x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
train_y = np.array([1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.])
```

Model creation

```
inpLayer = tf.keras.layers.Input(1)
hiddenLayer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='relu')(inpLayer)
outputLayer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hiddenLayer)    
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inpLayer, outputLayer)

model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy', metrics)
model.fit(train_x, train_y, 1, 10000, 2)
```

These are my results after 10 000 iterations model.predict(np.array([1, 2])):

```
model.predict(np.array([1, 2])):
                                [[0.50000435]
                                 [0.50000435]]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

If your labels are only 0 and 1, use the `to_categorical` function and convert them into a binary list

Then change the activation of the last layer of the model to an `softmax`

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
y = to_categorical(y)
```

Comment: Why it can't be like I have it above? Binary is used if my labels are only 0s and 1s, so this should be alright...

Comment: What you need is whether the model says 0 or 1. For this you must use softmax. softmax's job is to print the probability of each label

Comment: It didn't solve my problem, still it throws bad probabilities.